# Compare a List of Paths and retrive the most common similar Part of it

Tags: c#, list, compare, filepath, similarity

Ay Folks,

I need to iterate through a list of Paths (imported from an Excel-Sheet as strings) and find the most common First-Part of the Path (D:\Data\NeededFolder).

To clarify:

```
arrListOfPaths{
"D:\Data\NeededFolder\X\XX\File.file",
"D:\Data\NeededFolder\X\XY\File.file",
"D:\Data\NeededFolder\Y\File.file",
"D:\Data\NeededFolder\Z\XZ\XY\File.file"
}
```

Thus, I don't know how long the Paths are (nor how deep the Folder-hierarchy is), but I know that the some part of all my Paths are the same everywhere but not which one.

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT: //solved

Thus @Serge Wautier linked me the Answer that worked, not the one i was hoping for tho, i can call it a day :)
Here the Code:

```
public static string FindCommonPath ( string Separator, List<string> Paths )
        {
            string CommonPath = String.Empty;
            List<string> SeparatedPath = Paths
                .First ( str => str.Length == Paths.Max ( st2 => st2.Length ) )
                .Split ( new string[ ] { Separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
                .ToList ( );

            foreach ( string PathSegment in SeparatedPath.AsEnumerable ( ) )
            {
                if ( CommonPath.Length == 0 && Paths.All ( str => str.StartsWith ( PathSegment ) ) )
                {
                    CommonPath = PathSegment;
                }
                else if ( Paths.All ( str => str.StartsWith ( CommonPath + Separator + PathSegment ) ) )
                {
                    CommonPath += Separator + PathSegment;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return CommonPath;
        }
```

Comment: 10 seconds of googling lead to this https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_common_directory_path#C.23

Comment: Well thanks, i guess. I honesty hoped for a more One-Liner like solution.

Comment: There are no one-liners, you must realize, it is not the spoon that bends :D

Comment: @PedroG.Dias I allways thought there is no spoon :O :D

Comment: @KonstantinJahnel: me too ;-)